# Is Google bigquery javascript API be available with gapi.client.request?

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

So current javascript api for bigquery leverages RpcRequest for synchronous query api call. Currently I can submit a set of queries in one http round trip by using RpcBatch.

Is there plan to migrate to gapi.client.HttpRequest for bigquery requests in the future? gapi documentation indicates RpcBatch is deprecated and should use HttpBatch instead.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should already be able to use HttpRequest and HttpBatch with BigQuery. All you need to do is to use the appropriate /bigquery/v2 REST URL to build your request with gapi.client.request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I actually tried it and was stuck with a 400. I'll do some digging in the evening and maybe post the code I am working with.